# key() on push reference in firebase

Tags: firebase

I am calling the key() method on the push reference but it is not working. I can see that the data is added to my firebase.
Here is my code:

```
function createRoom(room){
  //will create a room with the json object passed into the
  //function and will return the key
  var roomRefRet = roomRef.child('ru').child('room').push(room);
  return roomRefRet.key();
}

var roomKey=createRoom({"name":"bathroom","capacity":"1"});
```

I am a newbie so I am probably missing something.

Comment: Works for me: when I log roomKey it is `-JcugcsfsJaYquS0rdAp`. See http://jsbin.com/niyeli/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks. Yes it works now. I was using the older version of Firebase. When I changed to 2.0.6 it started working. Incidentally the Firebase server that you are using in JSBin is it one anyone can use? A test sever?

Comment: It is just a Firebase that I set up for StackOverflow-related fiddles/bins. Its limits are the same as any hacker-plan Firebase and I clean up data as I see fit. So only use it if you're willing to lose it, but I would recommend storing your test data in your own hacker-plan Firebase. The hacker plan is pretty much meant for that.

Comment: The `key` method was introduced in Firebase 2.0, before that it was called `name`. And while 2.0 is **backwards** compatible (meaning that the `name` method still works, but logs a warning) the 1.x version is not **forwards** compatible (the `key` method didn't exists and they didn't retroactively add it). I'll vote to close your question as a typo if you don't mind, since this type of version mismatch loses value rapidly over time.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for explaining. Please go ahead and vote to remove the question. I agree with your view.